# Merging two OneNote 2010 notenbooks

Tags: merge, microsoft-onenote

I copied a OneNote 2010 notebook to a new Sharepoint location but unfortunately changes were made in both locations. Is there a way to "merge" these two OneNote files so that all changes are sychronized?

Comment: Could you merge each section of one of the notebooks with the other notebook? http://www.addictivetips.com/microsoft-office/merge-onenote-2010-notebooks/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way is to drag the notes from one to the other and then delete the one you don't want.

Comment: That's how I finally did it.